# Given a set of points representing all of the vertices of a shape in n-dimensional space, is there an algorithm to define that shape?

Tags: geometry, algorithms, euclidean-geometry

I'm trying to devise an algorithm for defining any arbitrary shape from a given set of points that represent all of the vertices of such a shape. It can be assumed that all the points in the set must be a vertex of that shape, thus all the points must be used once and only once, and they will only be used as a vertex. It can also be assumed that the shape will never be self-intersecting.

A simple example would be a set of 4 points in 2D space: {(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 1), (1, 0)}. We all know this would be a quadrilateral, specifically a square. I am, however, struggling to rigorously define a set of instructions that will guarantee these points will always define a square. More generally, I need an algorithm that can define a shape with any number of vertices in n-dimensional space. (However, in practice, the first implementation of this algorithm will have a maximum of 255 spatial dimensions.)

Is there any set of points that could result in an ill-defined shape? If so, what other information do I need to include in the algorithm to define the shape in order to avoid the possibility of a shape having multiple ways of being defined from the given set of points?

If it helps, ultimately, I want to be able to perform calculations on the shape such as finding the surface area, volume, the sum of all the angles, etc. Additionally, I intend to be able to graphically draw the shape if it is defined in 1, 2, or 3 spatial dimensions.

Comment: You may or may not want the convex hull, in which case: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull

Comment: In the example that you gave, the 4 points could also lie on a circle that circumscribes the unit square. Therefore, the point set alone is not unique enough to define the shape.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan, I don't want to limit the algorithm to convex sets. I'd like to be able to define a concave shape as well.

Comment: @vvg Thank you for pointing this out. This emphasizes the question of what additional information do I need to ensure that the set of points can only define the shape as intended.

Comment: I am not an expert in this, but from my background in engineering drawing (and faint recollection), we could reconstruct an orthographic projection of a 3D shape from projections (i.e., plan and elevation aka the top view of a shape and the front view of the shape). So, you may look at computing the projections and reconstructing the shape from the projections. 
See: Alexa, M et al. "Computing and Rendering Point Set Surfaces". url: https://www.sci.utah.edu/~shachar/Publications/crpss.pdf

Comment: After you determine the convex hull, if there are any vertices left that are not on the hull then the result is ambiguous. For example, suppose you have 4 two-dimensional points,  three that form a triangle and one point in the interior. Any of the triangle's sides could be replaced by two sides making a concave dent to the interior point. If there are several interior points to include then the number of possibilities grows large very fast. The same happens in 3d, where any face of the convex hull can be replaced by an inverted pyramid to turn an interior point into a vertex.